# How to give a sprite node a unique id

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Be gentle, I have looked over and over but can't find a understandable answer for me as a beginner with SpriteKit.

Situation: several different images to fall in the game, a tap moves the image to one of two specific places at the bottom. How can I name every image unique so it can find it's way to the according place.

E.g. Img1->Place1 Img2->Place1 Img3->Place2 Img4->Place1 Img5->Place2

Thanks for your thinking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to post some code to get some answers, people on stack overflow will not do the work for you.

What have you tried so far?

Are you not giving each image a name already like

```
 var image1: SKSpriteNode!
```

and setting it in ViewDiDLoad like so

```
image1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Img1")
```

Now you can do something for that image in your game like

```
 image1.position = ....
```

You could also give each image a unique name. Create a global struct

```
struct ImageName {
    static let image1 = "Image1"
    static let image2 = "Image2"
}
```

and than give each image a name

```
  image1.name = ImageName.image1
  image2.name = ImageName.image2
```

and than use the name property to identify each image like so

```
 self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("//\(ImageName.image1)") {
        node, stop in

    // do something for image1
 }
```

Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am aware of the fact some code would be better to get answers but in this case I tried to get some hints and figure it out myself in code. Glad you gave me a way to think over and work out.

Comment: My pleasure, let me know how it goes